# how to remove sub list

Tags: list, scala

How can I remove all occurrences of a sublist from a list, eg

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 10, 5).removeSubList(4, 5)
```

should remove all occurrences of (4, 5) (in this order!), so it returns

```
List(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 10, 5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recursive solution using `indexOfSlice`:

```
def removeSubList(l: List[Int], sublist: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.indexOfSlice(sublist) match {
  case -1 => l
  case index => removeSubList(l.patch(index, Nil, sublist.length), sublist)
}

// all of these print List(1 ,2 ,3):
println(removeSubList(List(1,2,3), List(4,5)))
println(removeSubList(List(1,2,3,4,5), List(4,5)))
println(removeSubList(List(4,5,1,2,3), List(4,5)))
println(removeSubList(List(4,5,1,2,4,5,3), List(4,5)))
```

**EDITED**:

- (thanks @corvus_192) reverting to using `indexOfSlice` version instead of using `diff`, which ignores sublist order.
- (thanks @The Archetypal Paul) using `patch` for cleaner removal of sublist

Comment: Your `removeSubList(List(1, 5, 4, 5, 2), List(4, 5))` returns `List(1, 2)` instead of `List(1, 5, 2)`

Comment: thanks @corvus_192 - reverted to original version using `indexOfSlice`

Comment: You could use `patch` to take the sublist out

Comment: The head of the list, before the removed slice should be outside of the recursive call: `l.slice(0, index) ++ removeSublist(l.slice(index + sublist.length, l.length), l.sublist)`. This is more efficient, and also fixes a bug: `List(4,4,5,5)` (assuming, the OP want's to end up with `List(4,5)` in this case, not with `Nil`).

Comment: Using `patch` actually makes this very slow, because you need to traverse `l` as many times as there are instances of `sublist`.

Comment: `indexOfSlice` results in 0 when `sublist` is empty resulting in this call never terminating: `removeSubList(1::2::3::4::Nil, Nil)`. For example `1::2::3::Nil indexOfSlice Nil` is `0`. I solve this in my version by taking a different branch when the sublist is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Tzach Zohar** idea with different implementation:

```
def removeSubList[T](list: List[T], sublist: List[T]): List[T] =
    if (list.containsSlice(sublist)) 
        removeSubList(list.diff(sublist), sublist)
    else list
```

Comment: I don't think so - OP wants all occurrences of (4,5) removed, while `List(4,5,1,4,5).diff(List(4,5))` would produce `List(1,4,5)`

Answer (score 0):

Variant on **Tzach Zohar** idea but with the assumption the OP wants a result that does not include the given sublist ever. Handles the case when `sublist` is empty

```
  /**
    * Return `s` with no occurrence of `target` present
    *
    * @param s
    * @param target
    * @return The sequence free of any occurrence of the target slice
    */
  def removeCompletely[E](s: Seq[E], target: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = {
    if (s.isEmpty || target.isEmpty)
      s
    else
      removeCompletely0(s, target)
  }

  private def removeCompletely0[E](s: Seq[E], target: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = {
    val sliceIdx = s.indexOfSlice(target)
    if (sliceIdx >= 0) {
      val patched = s.patch(sliceIdx, s take 0, target.size)
      removeCompletely0(patched, target)
    }
    else {
      s
    }
  }
```